# Stored procedure called from spring returns all results. (doens't execute the where statement)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, spring-jdbc

I'm working with a project in spring and i must call a standard procedure that is a simple Select *.
I have the stored prcoedure:

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
"INTER_ADMIN"."SIMPLEPROCEDURE"(
   personId IN VARCHAR2, dbDataOut OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN dbDataOut
  FOR SELECT *
    FROM ACONTRATO
    WHERE PERSONID = personId;
END;`

And i want to display my consult as webservice with springboot.
When i execute my service it doesn't execute my where clause and it displays all results i have in table ACONTRATO.
My serviceRepository is the folowing below.

```
<!-- language: lang-java-->
simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName).declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("dbDataOut",OracleTypes.CURSOR, new ConsultaContratoRowMapper()),
        new SqlParameter("personId", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
SqlParameterSource inParams = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("personId", "50", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult =  simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);

return (List<ConsultaContratoOutput>)simpleJdbcCallResult.get("dbDataOut");`
```

Can anybody tell me whats the problem and why my SPROC doesnt execute the where clause?
PS: for simpliflying i defined all my types from my table ACONTRATO as VARCHAR2

tks in advance

Comment: SQL is not case sensitive. `PERSONID = personId` is simply like `1 = 1`. Bind variables has to be explicitly specified like `:personId`. In PL/SQL, you always name the local variables like `l_personId`

Comment: Or for parameters, `p_personid` or similar, to indicate that it’s not a variable. Or, prefix with the procedure name, for example `simpleprocedure.personid`.